Plotting polygons with holes in rgl?
I have various polygons, created with the terra package, which I want to plot using the rgl package. But they have holes. And I can't seem to understand how to use rgl to do so. In the example of the help file of the triangulate() function, it clearly shows that plotting polygons with holes is possible. I tried to adapt this example to another example but failed. Here is my code:
library(rgl)
library(terra)

# dummy data
geom <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  "object" = 1,
  "part" = 1,
  "x" = c(1,2,6,7,1,3,3,5,3,5,6,6,5),
  "y" = c(1,5,5,3,1,3,4,4,3,3,4,3,3),
  "hole" = c(rep(0,5), rep(1,4), rep(2,4))))

# show in 2d plot
poly <- terra::vect(geom, "polygons")
terra::plot(poly, col = "forestgreen")

# prepare coordinates
x <- c(geom[geom[,5] == 0,3], NA, geom[geom[,5] == 1,3], NA, geom[geom[,5] == 2,3])
y <- c(geom[geom[,5] == 0,4], NA, geom[geom[,5] == 1,4], NA, geom[geom[,5] == 2,4])

# show in 2d plot
plot(x, y, type = "n")
polygon(x, y)

# try to triangulate
triangulate(x, y, plot = TRUE)

# show in 3d plot
open3d()
polygon3d(x, y, 0, col = "red")

I always get Error in processOutside(i) : Cannot triangulate polygon. As I understand the example in the help file, my code should work. I understand it in a way that I simply have to separate the holes from the main polygon with NAs. Am I missing something?

EDIT:  The unreleased version 1.3.15 of rgl uses code from https://github.com/mapbox/earcut.hpp, which is much faster and more reliable than the original R code.  I'll leave my original answer below for users of older versions,
but the workaround is no longer necessary.
ORIGINAL ANSWER:
This is a bug or limitation in the rgl::triangulate() function, but there are workarounds.
The main issue is that triangulation is a difficult numerical problem:  it needs to figure out which triplets of vertices can make triangles that don't overlap areas that are outside the area of your polygon.  When vertices line up, the tests sometimes produce incorrect results due to rounding errors.
So one thing you can do is to avoid having your vertices all lining up so well.  For example, after creating the x and y vectors, you could replace them with jitter(x, factor = 0.01) and jitter(y, factor = 0.01) which adds a small amount of fuzz to each value and avoids the collinearity problem.  This will distort your data a bit, but you probably won't notice it in the plot.  And if you really want, you can use the triangulation of the jittered data to define a triangulation of the real data.
Another issue is determining whether the holes are holes, or are overlapping polygons.  It's best to be consistent about ordering your vertices, e.g. clockwise around areas that you want to include, and counter-clockwise around the holes.  (This might be an actual requirement, but I think triangulate() tries to fix things if it can.)
Finally, your polygons repeated the first vertex as the last one.  The triangulate() function gets a bit confused by that.
So with these changes I get it to work, some of the time:
library(rgl)

set.seed(3)

# dummy data
# dummy data
geom <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  "object" = 1,
  "part" = 1,
  "x" = c(1,2,6,7,3,3,5,5,6,6),
  "y" = c(1,5,5,3,3,4,4,3,4,3),
  "hole" = c(rep(0,4), rep(1,3), rep(2,3))))

# prepare coordinates
x <- c(geom[geom[,5] == 0,3], NA, 
       rev(geom[geom[,5] == 1,3]), NA, 
       rev(geom[geom[,5] == 2,3]))
y <- c(geom[geom[,5] == 0,4], NA, 
       rev(geom[geom[,5] == 1,4]), NA, 
       rev(geom[geom[,5] == 2,4]))

x <- jitter(x, factor = 0.01)
y <- jitter(y, factor = 0.01)

# show in 2d plot
plot(x, y, type = "n")

# try to triangulate
triangulate(x, y, plot = TRUE)


#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,]    8    1    1   12    1   12    7    7    4    12     3    11
#> [2,]    7   12   10    6    4    3    2    6   11    11     2     4
#> [3,]    1    8   12    8   10    6    1    2   10     3     6     3
#> attr(,"nextvert")
#>  [1]  4  1  2  3 NA  8  6  7 NA 12 10 11

Created on 2024-09-25 with reprex v2.1.1
I say "some of the time", because with some set.seed() values it still fails.

Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I don't think it's suffiecient if it works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't. I guess I need to try and find another solution somehow...The bad thing is, that faulty runs don't always throw warnings or errors. So I would need to check visually...

I think the only ways to get something reliable is to use a different package than rgl for the triangulation, or to fix the triangulate() function in rgl.  However, I don't know what package does it well.

@Zoe, what did you end up doing?  Did you find a reliable method?

Until now, I simply gave up :(
